How to find the shortest line segment connecting two skew lines, with constraint that line is parallel to some plane?
I've found lots of examples for how to identify the shortest line segment connecting two skew lines. For example, here: Distance between Skew lines
However, for purposes of a simple game engine I am writing, I need to solve this with the additional constraint that the solution line must be parallel to the xy plane. I am using right-handed coordinate system, with xy plane as the "floor".
My first thought was to write the distance between two "level" points on the two lines as a function of z, and then take the derivative of this function and solve for the "trough", where the derivative is zero. But I am not skilled enough with calculus to solve this.
I believe this additional constraint introduces new cases where a solution may not be found, or where multiple solutions exist. But for purposes of my engine, I can code with the assumption that any lines which I must find distances for do not lie parallel to the xy plane.

You can try to find the minimum of the square of the distance, not the distance itself. It should be much easier.

Taking the derivative of the distance between two points on a translating plane was not as hard as I feared.
For two lines, each defined by a point on the xy plane and a direction vector with z component 1, the distance between two points on these lines with shared z is given by:
$P:(a,b,0), d_P:(c,d,1)$
$Q:(e,f,0), d_Q:(g,h,1)$
$dist(z)=((x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2)^{1/2} = ((e+gz)-(a+cz))^2+((f+hz)-(b+dz))^2)^{1/2}$
Squaring the distance does indeed make taking the derivative easier. (Thanks @Trebor.) We can do this safely because the distance will never be negative, and both functions will have the same minimum.
$d/dz [(e+gz)-(a+cz))^2+((f+hz)-(b+dz))^2] = -2c(a+cz) - 2(d-h)(-b-z(d-h) + f) + g$
Setting the derivative of the distance equal to zero and solving for z gives us the z value at which the two lines are closest to each other, subject to our constraint.
$z = \frac{-2ac+2b(d-h)-2df+2fh+g}{2(c^2-(d-h)^2}$
